# "git add ." is not adding the files in the staged area

Tags: php, git

I am trying to add the files for commit using "git add ." but the files are not getting added!

This is the output of my "git status" :

```
 git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   ../bharat-mitra-todo.txt
#   modified:   ../config/main.php
#   modified:   ../controllers/SiteController.php
#   modified:   esearch (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   ../views/feedback/index.php
#   modified:   ../views/layouts/main.php
#   modified:   ../views/site/sitemap.php
#   modified:   ../views/user/admin.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ../modules/rights/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And this is what I get after **git add .** and then **git status**

**SAME OUTPUT AS ABOVE!!**

```
git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   ../bharat-mitra-todo.txt
#   modified:   ../config/main.php
#   modified:   ../controllers/SiteController.php
#   modified:   esearch (modified content, untracked content)
#   modified:   ../views/feedback/index.php
#   modified:   ../views/layouts/main.php
#   modified:   ../views/site/sitemap.php
#   modified:   ../views/user/admin.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ../modules/rights/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This is the first time I am facing this problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you typed `git status` again. Try `git add ../`

Comment: The `.` in Unix means current directory. When you type `git add .`, you are telling git to add all changes in the current directory. It looks like you don't have any changes in the current directory, but in the parent directory. `..` in unix signifies parent directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it not because the modified files are not in the current directory? `git add .` will add the files in the current directory to the staging area.

If you do `git add ../` this should work fine.

Comment: Yup that was the issue. I just figured it now. Thank you!